# Reading files in PhoneGap/Cordova 3.1

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

So, I'm developing an app that requires a prepopulated database. According to [Raymon Camden](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/phonegap-storage-api/eng/), there's no direct way in packaging a pre-made database with the app. As a solution, I'll execute a `Select count(*)...` statement to check and insert `if result <= 0`,

Now problem is the insertion. I have ~500 rows for a table, and I don't want to paste them in the js file. I found the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) and I believe I can read the `.sql` file, then execute.

**Questions:**

1. How does PhoneGap 3.1 (*ugh, naming.*) package apps? In my `www` directory I have

   - js
   - css
   - dev

     - data.sql

   So, initially I thought `fileSystem.root.getFile('/dev/data.sql', ...` would work. (Basing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399465/where-does-localfilesystem-persistent-point-to), where MattDavis said app data goes to `/data/data/packageName`.)
2. How do I **access** the file?
3. Am I on the right track? Or, is there a better approach?

I am using Cordova 3.1 to build, with the [awesome support of Netbeans](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/official_support_for_phonegap_in).

**EDIT**

I tried creating a `.txt` file on the root dir of my device. I can successfully access it with `fileSystem.root.getFile('test.txt', ...)`. And so I infer that I simply need to get the *actual app* directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`How did I access the file?` + `Or, is there a better approach?`

AJAX. It turns out that I can access the assets folder through:

```
    $.get('file:///android_asset/www/dev/data.sql', function(response){
        console.log('Data found!');
        console.log(response); 
    });
```

I am not sure if this'll work with other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your in right track only. Because your access with in `asset/www/dev/` inside data.sql.

`/data/data/packageName` this is for accessing **SD** inside your app (app internal storage). so no need do like that.

Comment: Not sure I understood what you meant, you mean like `fileSystem.root.getFile('asset/www/dev/data.sql', ...`?

Comment: You can continue your work with `fileSystem.root.getFile('asset/www/dev/data.sql', ...`. It will work. no worry about `/data/data/packageName` etc...

Comment: Uhhh. Unfortunately, I still can't seem to access the file. :|